Hazelcast is starting in a Java modular environment (Java 9 and newer) but without proper access to required Java packages
Java 21 with Spring boot 3.3.2 and Hazelcast 5.4.0 application has warning at the time of startup

Hazelcast is starting in a Java modular environment (Java 9 and newer) but without proper access to required Java packages.
Use additional Java arguments to provide Hazelcast access to Java internal API.
The internal API access is used to get the best performance results.
Arguments to be used:
--add-modules java.se
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED


Is there a solution other than passing arguments to the service.
